# Spring Security 3 Java Config

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am migrating the Spring Security from xml to java and I am facing the issue:

> j_spring_security_check : The requested resource is not available.

The security is working fine with xml but switching to java is giving the error.

**This is working fine**

Spring security xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/userOnly**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>

    </security:http>

    <!-- authentication manager -->
    <security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- password encoder -->
    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />
</beans>
```

Security Config

```
package com.src.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;

import com.src.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:spring-security-context.xml")
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public UserService userService(){
        return new UserService();
    }

}
```

**This is not working**

Security Config

```
package com.src.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;

import com.src.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@ImportResource(value = "classpath:spring-security-context.xml")
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean(name="userService")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserService userService(){
        return new UserService();
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(new StandardPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/signin").failureUrl("/signin?error=1")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .and()
            .csrf();
    }

}
```

Comment: What error you got? And what Template-Engine you use?

Comment: post your error log, It's easy to identify

Comment: Do you really use Spring Security 3.x? - I ask because they change the name of `j_spring_security_check ` in Spring Security 4.0.

Comment: I am not getting any error log. Only "j_spring_security_check : The requested resource is not available" on the browser. I am using Security 3.x

Comment: When using java config the login url is `/login` and not `/j_spring_security_check`. Either change your page to post to `/login` or set the `loginProcessingUrl` to `/j_spring_security_check`.

Comment: Ok ...here is my latest code , changed from /j_spring_security_check to /login. But getting the same error : "/login - resource not availble".

Comment: Security Config                                                                                                                   @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
   .and()
   .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
   .and()
   .csrf();
  
 }

Comment: Ok I have solved the issue... thanks to @deinum and the java doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html